# On a webpage, if the user never clicked on any page element at all, is the body element first to get any keyboard event?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

It seems the `body` element is first element to get the `keydown` or `keypress` event, and then `html`, `document`, and `window` (and these are the only 4 elements that will get the event -- no other element will get it), but I am not entirely sure.  Is this actually spec'ed some where?

That is, if there is no input focus or not element is clicked on or has the focus, then it is "global" keyboard events, and the order is: `body`, `html`, `document`, `window` -- four and only four elements. Is this spec'ed some where?

(this is somewhat related to this question: [How should a modal dialog's key event handler be used using ReactJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62194896/how-should-a-modal-dialogs-key-event-handler-be-used-using-reactjs) )

It is difficult to try it inside a JSFiddle or inside a snippet here, as the rendered result is inside an iframe.  But if you are inclined to try things out, here is the whole webpage:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
      #outer {
        width: 600px;
        height: 400px;
        background: orange;
      }
      #inner {
        width: 300px;
        height: 200px;
        background: #07f;
      }
      input {
        width: 210px;
        background: yellow;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="outer">
      <div id="inner">
        <input id="inner-input" />
      </div>
      <input id="outer-input" />
    </div>

    <script>
      document
        .querySelector("#inner-input")
        .addEventListener("keydown", function (ev) {
          console.log("inner input", ev);
        });

      document
        .querySelector("#outer-input")
        .addEventListener("keydown", function (ev) {
          console.log("outer input", ev);
        });

      document
        .querySelector("#outer")
        .addEventListener("keydown", function (ev) {
          console.log("outer div", ev);
        });

      document
        .querySelector("#inner")
        .addEventListener("keydown", function (ev) {
          console.log("inner div", ev);
        });

      document
        .querySelector("body")
        .addEventListener("keydown", function (ev) {
          console.log("body", ev);
        });

      document
        .querySelector("html")
        .addEventListener("keydown", function (ev) {
          console.log("html", ev);
        });

      document.addEventListener("keydown", function (ev) {
        console.log("document", ev);
      });

      window.addEventListener("keydown", function (ev) {
        console.log("window", ev);
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

body would be the first because events travel from innermost to outermost nodes.

Comment: the concern is not about keydown or keypress. The concern is about which elements

Comment: depends upon the way events are added.
refer bubbling vs capturing. By default events are triggered from inwards towards outwards.

https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing

Comment: on Stackoverflow, it doesn't mean you should answer whatever you know to a question. You should really answer what is being asked.  Your answer is totally unrelated to what is being asked. I didn't downvote you by the way. Somebody else did.

Comment: What I meant to say is that body would not be the first to get the event. It would be the last. Because events travel from innermost to outermost node, given that same event has been binded to multiple nodes.

Comment: no... do you know what you are talking about.  When it bubbles up, the child gets the event before the parent node

Comment: that's what I said. innermost to outermost

Comment: quoting what you said "What I meant to say is that body would not be the first to get the event. It would be the last. Because events travel from innermost to outermost node, given that same event has been binded to multiple nodes. – Udbhav"

Comment: My bad, I was considering body to be the outermost element.
But when considering document and window as well, body would be the innermost element.